# Does Linkshare support tracking of in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, tracking, in-app

Does Linkshare support tracking of in-app purchases?
What if a user download my free version from an affiliate link, and then decide to purchase an in-app only after two days. How can I track these sales?

Answer (score 1):

**Does Linkshare support tracking of in-app purchases?**

LinkShare will report sales of in-app purchases but at a "category" level.  Look for something like "ITS 3P IOS INAPP PX4."  This can be found in an "Individual Items" report.  Further, if you have been using Signature tracking you can find these sales in an Signature Orders report.

**What if a user download my free version from an affiliate link, and then decide to purchase an in-app only after two days. How can I track these sales?**

Yes, this is the only way to earn commissions an in-app purchase.  You can't initiate an affiliate session with an in-app purchase.  In-app purchases can only earn a commission if the affiliate session is already open.